# Magento 2 - Layered navigation (price navigation) only works in default store view

Tags: magento, navigation, multisite, layered-navigation

*SOLVED*

Update to version 2.3.2 solved this problem.

Using Magento 2.3.1, have noticed that price navigation in layered navigation is just working in my default store view (the first store view I created).
The price navigation for the other store views isn't showing up at all.
All store views have the same settings as default config.

I'm not using any layered navigation extensions.
Reindex, cleared cache doesn't solve the problem.
I've tried to add new store views as well, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you have to follow this step

1) Regenerate your static content by running the following command

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

2) After Regenerate the static content clear cache and re-index using following command

```
php bin/magento index:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Nops, it doesn't solve this problem. Already tested a number of times.
If I create a new store view, the price navigation doesn't work either.

Comment: I think its working I have checked https://www.sanmic.tk/svensk-mat?manufacturer=61 and https://www.sanmic.tk/svensk-mat?manufacturer=61

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work. Every layered navigation except for "price navigation" works. Check this page for example: https://www.sanmicen.tk/swedish-food
However, in the swedish version this works as expected: https://www.sanmic.tk/svensk-mat

Comment: have you deleted Manufacturer attribute in admin?

Comment: I've tried some different approaches, that's why you may have seen other errors.
Now everything is back at the same spot again.
I've even compared sql queries using DB profiler, but nothing differ from the two store views, except for store_ids and such obvious differences between the store views.
This problem seems impossible to solve :/

Comment: Is it possible to talk in different platform?

Comment: Have you got an email I can contact you on?

Comment: My email id jscatoz@gmail.com